# What is the Anjuta project template (automake) *.wiz format (syntax)?

Tags: templates, gnome, anjuta

Apparently it's XML-like. Example templates can be found in the gnome Anjuta shares on an Ubuntu install at `/usr/share/anjuta/project/`

I think I'll go back to Eclipse and gedit if it doesn't look like Anjuta has documented a decent auto-completion, project build, and syntax-highlighting template format. Others with the same question went fishing on Ubuntu forums and had no luck.

The answer might also help people trying to build automake scripts for svn repos at [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5926366/using-anjuta-with-svn-how-to-create-the-project]

Comment: What's your question exactly?

Comment: Where can I find out how to write Anjuta project template files (*.wiz)?

Answer (score 1):

A bit overdue, but I found [the official documentation](https://developer.gnome.org/libanjuta/stable/project-wizard-format.html), and remembered having seen your post. From the docs:

> The template files look like xml documents and have normally the
>   extension .wiz. All templates and others related files are installed
>   by default in `$anjuta_install_dir/share/anjuta/templates`. But the
>   project wizard looks for templates in the sub directory
>   `anjuta/templates` of all user data directories as defined by `XDG Base`
>   `Directory Specification` too. It is possible to override a Anjuta
>   project template by an user one put, by example, in
>   `~/.local/share/anjuta/templates`.
>
> The template file is divided in four parts: an header block, one or
>   more page blocks, a content block and an optional action block. The
>   file is read several times, one time for each block but before reading
>   it, the whole file go though a transformation pass and only the
>   resulting file must be a valid xml file. The transformation pass uses
>   autogen.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: @deW1 I cannot include 8 pages of text in a post. Well, I could, but I don't think it would be correct. And this link points to the official documentation - if that disappears, using the .wiz format wouldn't make much sense anymore, would it? (Did you check the linked page?)

Comment: @jcoppens what about a short summary? and mentioning that it's the official documentation before people click it?

Comment: @DanGetz Why do I get -2 for this reply? (Apart from the fact that the reply itself is marked with -1)

Comment: @jcoppens the -2 points must have been from whoever downvoted your post. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation for the amount of points gained or lost for different things.